# How to convert a Row_number() in a SQL query into a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: performance, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I would like to convert this SQL query into a [LINQ to Entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework#LINQ_to_Entities) query. If anyone has a solution, please share it with me.

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Country, Year ORDER BY InvoiceId ASC) AS RowNo,
    Country,
    Year,
    InvoiceId
FROM
    Invoice
```

My SQL Server table `Invoice` looks like this:

```
InvoiceId | FinancialYear | Country  | InvoiceNo
----------+---------------+----------+-----------
1         |  2017         | India    |  1
2         |  2017         | India    |  2
3         |  2018         | Indian   |  1
4         |  2017         | USA      |  1
5         |  2018         | USA      |  2
```

Comment: And what have **you tried** so far? Please show us your current efforts!

Comment: @marc_s I have tried this but unfortunately could not go ahead. please help me if possible.  **var data = dbContext.Invoice.OrderBy(c => c.InvoiceId).GroupBy(g => new { g.Country, g.Year }).Select(c => new{c, count= c.Count() }).SelectMany()**

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.